# Make the Userform in Outlook stay on the screen - VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, userform

So I have created a VBA Macro embedded withing Outlook. The code runs a userform.

When I run my macro:

**Currently:**

- When I minimize Outlook, my userform also minimizes.

**What I Want:**

- When I minimize outlook I want my userform to stay on the screen.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I am using vbModeless to display my userform, as i want the user to access the outlook content while the userform is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim olapp As Object
    Set olapp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    olapp.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1
End Sub
```

This will minimize Outlook the moment userform is shown.
Not exactly what you want (what you describe is a bit complicated), but nearly the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i still have the same problem; when i minimize outlook, userform minimizes also.

This just minimizes outlook when the userform runs the first time. But if I maximize outlook, then minimize again...the userform minimizes also.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way around this, maybe there is no way to achieve what I want. I would probably have to code a .net standalone application.